# How can I run only one test from a suite?

Tags: php, codeception

I have this test class below, and I want to run only one test from it, for example the "aboutPage". Any ideas how?

This is how I run only this file:

```
codecept run tests/acceptance/VisitorCest.php
```

But now I want to run only one test from the file.

```
<?php
use \AcceptanceTester;

class VisitorCest
{
    public function _before(){}
    public function _after(){}

    public function aboutPage(AcceptanceTester $I)
    {
        $I->wantTo('check about page');
    }

    public function contactPage(AcceptanceTester $I)
    { 
        $I->wantTo('check contact page');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 161, accepted):

You simply append a colon and the function name, like this:

```
codecept run tests/acceptance/VisitorCest.php:myTestName
```

or a shorter version:

```
codecept run acceptance VisitorCest:myTestName
```

(Notice the space between the suite-name and the file-name.)

Comment: just a note. you cannot run a single test if it is a **unit** test (extended from **PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase**) as **codeception** has no **filter** option (unlike **phpunit**)

Comment: codecept run unit/TestThatExtendsPHPUnit.php:testMethod works just fine for me.

Comment: You can omit the `.php` filename extension, like this: `codecept run -- -c frontend unit models/ContactFormTest:testSendEmail`

Comment: `myTestName` doesn't have to be the full test name either. It will run any tests with a partial match

Comment: How can I run with dependencies too?

Answer (score 41):

this is what works:

**codecept run {suite-name} {file-name}.php:{function-name}**

*notice the space between the suite-name and the file-name*

Comment: technically you have the more general solution. but as proven, most people like seeing examples instead.

Comment: Do not need the `.php` part.

Comment: @tivnet This is only true for Codeception 2.x

Answer (score 24):

In addition to the answer provided by *@Tzook Bar Noy* you can **add a trailing `$` when there are multiple tests which start with the same name**. Consider the following example:

```
<?php

use \AcceptanceTester;

class VisitorCest
{
    public function aboutPage(AcceptanceTester $I)
    {
    }

    public function aboutPageOption(AcceptanceTester $I)
    { 
    }
}
```

Where the following command will execute both of the tests:

```
codecept run tests/acceptance/VisitorCest.php:aboutPage
```

This will execute only the first:

```
codecept run tests/acceptance/VisitorCest.php:aboutPage$
```

Answer (score 14):

A more proper way of doing this will be to assign a group annotation to the test case in question. This is preferable for the following reason;
If you have two test cases for example in the same class VisitorCest;

```
public function aboutPage
public function aboutPage2
```

Executing

```
codecept run tests/acceptance/VisitorCest.php:aboutPage
```

will run both VisitorCest:aboutPage and VisitorCest:aboutPage2 test cases.

Assign a group to a test case like this

```
/**
 * @group aaa
 */
public function aboutPage(AcceptanceTester $I)
{
}
```

And execute this particular test case like this

`codecept run -g aaa`

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the previous answers, you can run one or several methods by grouping by a given name:

```
/**
 * @group test-aboutPage
 */
public function aboutPage(AcceptanceTester $I)
{
    $I->wantTo('check about page');
}
```

Use the option `-g` and the name of the group:

```
$ codecept run acceptance VisitorCest -g test-aboutPage
```

Comment: I would prefer slightly different way , since you can tab in that case and easily navigate to a desired Cest,  ` codecept run tests/acceptance/VisitorCest  -group test-aboutPage`

Answer (score 2):

this is what I do.

`php codecept.phar run unit UnitNameTest.php`

Comment: Irrelevant to the question asked

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `PHP Yii2 Framework`, then you can run only one test using this command.

Make sure you are in tests directory.

```
cd /codeception/frontend

codecept run -vv acceptance HomeCept
```

Comment: That's not related to Yii2, but to the fact that a `Cept` only contains one test, but a `Cest` can contain multiple tests - see the initial question

Answer (score 0):

Today I learned more general answer to this question. There is a hidden way to **run arbitrary list of Codeception tests**. Let's say you want to run Cest1.php, Cest2.php, Cest3.php and nothing else. They are all from different suites, different groups, etc.

This is the sample code to achieve this:

```
codecept run -o "groups: custom: [Cest1.php, Cest2.php, Cest3.php]" -g custom
```

The trick is you define a group on-the-fly, include needed tests into it and execute tests from newborn group immediately in single command.

Answer (score -3):

Try it
phpunit --filter {TestMethodName} {FilePath}